# Can you use list.index for a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, object, indexing

If I have a list of objects made from classes, is there a way to get the index of a particular object in that list?

I've tried using list.index like this:

```
    obj_list = [object1(), object2()]
    object1_index = obj_list.index(object1())
    return object1_index
```

But this just returns a ValueError, saying that object1() is not in list, even though it is.

Comment: Is `object1` the name of the class? If so `object1()` (with the parentheses) instantiates a new object, which is not what you are likely trying to do here.

Comment: Unless your classes implement `__eq__`, you can expect `obj_list.index` to fail at finding an anonymous object.

Comment: BTW, `object1()` is already incorrect, because you create an object from a class. It should be `Class1()` instead. `object1 = Class1()` where `()` means *create an object of that class*

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since you provide example in Python, that would be great to fit the most used coding-style in order to help us read your code. In its current states, we have to do more effort in order to read it. For example, the naming convention for classes is CapWords. Also, try to avoid classes named "object", it might confuse readers. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object1` is a constructor; each time you say `object1()` you're constructing a new object of class `object1`.  Hence the `object1()` in your `index()` call does not refer to the same object as the one in `obj_list`.

You could do something like:

```
next(i for i, x in enumerate(obj_list) if isinstance(x, object1))
```

to find the index of the first object in `obj_list` that is an instance of `object1`.